# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los array de otras funciones y guardarlos en uno nuevo con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

lo que necesito hacer es poder pasar unos **`array`** que están en diferentes funciones a una función **"final"**, la verdad no se por donde empezar por que no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

el código original es muy extenso por esta razón cree unos de ejemplo que mas o menos es lo que hacen.

```
//#######################################################
function funcion1(){
var array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
var receptor=[]
receptor.push(array1)
}
funcion1()

//#######################################################
function funcion2(){
var receptor = [];
var array2 = []
var condicion;
  if(condicion = true){
      array2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
  }else{
      array2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] 
  }
  receptor.push(array2)
}
funcion2()

//#######################################################
//Función objetivo
function objetivo(receptor){
   var rec = receptor
// console.log(rec) =  [array1, array2,....]
}
objetivo()
```

> Bien como se aprecia la función1 y función2 tienen `arreglos` con los datos que quiero pasar a la función final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras, pero esta resuelve lo que deseas hacer:

```
function array1() {
   var array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   return array1;
}

function array2() {
   var array2 = [6,7,8,9,10];
   return array2;
}

//esta funcion final() retorna los dos arrays concatenados
//de las funciones anteriores
function final() {
   var miArray1 = array1();
   var miArray2 = array2();
   var arrayFinal = miArray1.concat(miArray2);
   return arrayFinal;
}

console.log(final());
```

Comment: gracias por responder. bien, primero me equivoque en el `console.log(rec) = [array1, array2,....]` lo que queria era `[[array1],[array2],....]` pero igua eso no es problema eso si lo se hacer xD.

Comment: aparentemente todo funciona bien, el error que da con uno de los `array` es mas bien otro tipo de problema fuera de esta pregunta. Muchas gracias por la ayuda compatriota.